# Can we ever find a linear transformation T : R 3 → R 4 which is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was trying to solve the statement by rank nullity theorem but got stuck.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Please show us your progress, so we can help.

Comment: Note that a linear map $T$ from vectorspaces $U$ and $V$ will necessarily have $\text{rank}(T)\leq (\text{dim}(U),\text{dim}(V))$.  Do you see why this is true or how you can prove it?  Now, for a linear transformation $T$ from $U$ to $V$ to be "onto", what does that say about the rank of $T$ compared to the dimension of $V$?

Comment: dim(range(T))+null(T)=dim(v) and dim(v)=3 , dim(range(T))=4 and null(T)>=0,so i think i have got my answer .Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is a linear transformation, there is a $4 \times 3$ matrix $A$ that characterizes $T$. Indeed, from the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), we know that
$$
rank(A) + nullity(A) = \dim \left( \mathbb{R}^3  \right)= 3.
$$

Can you explain what $rank(A)$ is, and if $T$ was onto, what should the value of $rank(A)$ be?

Comment: rank(A)=dim(range(T)) which should be 4.

Comment: thank you,I got my answer Actually i was using rank nullity theorem used in matrices not in linear transformation .(kernel and range )

Comment: @AYUSHAZAD indeed from your comment above sounds like you got it

Answer (score 1):

No.  Linear transformations don't increase dimension.  You can use the rank-nullity theorem to see it.  In this case, the rank is at most three.  But the rank is the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: A linear trnasformation is defined when the images of a basis is known. It follows that the image can be generate only by three vectors (in $\mathbb R^4$ in this case) so the space image can be at most of dimension three.